# I have to find palindrome of a number in Pl/SQl without using conditional statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

this code is to check whether the given number is a palindrome
I want to know can we perform the same program without using conditional statements such as(for while loop if-else )

```
declare
    n number;
    m number;
    rev number:=0;
    r number;
begin
    n:=12321;
    m:=n;
    while n>0
    loop
        r:=mod(n,10);
        rev:=(rev*10)+r;
        n:=trunc(n/10);
    end loop;
    
    if m=rev
    then
        dbms_output.put_line('number is palindrome');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('number is not palindrome');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Most (all?) database engines use a particular SQL dialect. Oracle's version is very different from TSQL (sql server). Please tag correctly.

Comment: The question makes no sense. The input is a number. The output is `true` **if** the number is palindromic and `false` otherwise. The problem itself is conditional by its very nature. I don't believe, in the entire history of computing (and its theoretical counterpart), there has ever been a method to solve a conditional problem without any kind of conditional processing. What is the background of your question?

Answer (score 1):

One option may be:

```sql
declare
  n             NUMBER := 12321;
  is_palindrome NUMBER(1);
begin
  SELECT 1
  INTO   is_palindrome
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE  SUBSTR(n, LEVEL, 1) = SUBSTR(n, -LEVEL, 1)
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(n)/2
  HAVING COUNT(1) = FLOOR(LENGTH(n)/2);
   
  dbms_output.put_line('number is palindrome');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('number is not palindrome');
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7cd7a5afd359634613475a3ceb37df55)*

Comment: Even leaving aside the question of whether a `connect by` query is a form of looping (keep on connecting until the "connect by" condition is not met), the `when` clause in the `exception` section is a basic conditional construct, is it not? I don't see how this achieves the stated task of writing a solution "without using conditional statements".

Comment: @mathguy You missed the "such as" from the quote. "without using conditional statements such as(for while loop if-else )" This does not use any of those listed statements. The OP was unclear on what exactly is restricted so this answer assumes that the only restricted things are those items explicitly listed in the question as if we eliminate every conditional statement then the question is impossible.

Comment: I didn't miss "such as". Perhaps you don't know what it means? It means "for example" - just the opposite of a **complete** list of what is disallowed. But your answer to my question is helpful - it shows where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do this without some conditional. You are asking to produce multiple possible outputs given a single input. This requires a conditional. However, you can reduce it to the only conditional in SQL: CASE. Further there is no need for pl/sql, it can be done with a single sql statement.

As of v19.5 Oracle supports the REVERSE function. So:

```
 with parm( val ) as 
      ( select to_char(&Number) from dual ) 
 select 'number is ' || 
        case when to_char(val) = to_char(reverse(val)) 
             then 'palindrome.'
             else 'not palindrome'
        end     
   from parm;
```

Older versions (11gr2 and later) which do not have the REVERSE function  (actually it might exist but undocumented, therefore should not be used), you can use a RECURSIVE subquery factoring (CTE).

```
 with parm( val ) as 
      ( select to_char(&Number) from dual ) 
    , rev( val, lav, n)  as 
      ( select val, substr(val, 1,1) , 1 from parm 
         union all 
        select val, substr(val, n+1,1) || lav , n+1 
          from rev
         where n < length(val) 
      ) 
select 'number is ' || 
       case when val = lav
            then 'palindrome.'
            else 'not palindrome'
       end 
  from (select val, lav 
          from rev 
         where n = length(val) 
       ) ;
```

Since your input is a number you have to decide what to do with leading 0.

Or without resorting to converting parameter to a string.

```
 with parm( val ) as
      ( select &Number from dual )
    , rev( val, lav, nval )  as
      ( select val, mod(val,10), trunc(val/10) 
          from parm
         union all
        select val, 10*lav + mod(nval,10),trunc(nval/10) 
          from rev
         where nval>0
      ) 
select 'number is ' ||
       case when val = lav
            then 'palindrome.'
            else 'not palindrome'
       end
  from rev where nval = 0;
```

This solution is Oracle, it may work in MS SQL Server, but I do not use it, so am not sure.